# PHP: Max and Min returning incorrect results

Tags: php, max, percentage, min

I am sure this is because of the "g" on the end but this is the scenario and results when I try and work out a ratio percent. I always want to divide the highest of 2 numbers by the lowest.

```
$item1 = "200.00g";
$item2 = "50.00g";
$calc = round((max($item1,$item2) / min($item1,$item2))*100) . "%";
// result: $calc = "400%"

$item1 = "100.00g";
$item2 = "5.00g";
$calc = round((max($item1,$item2) / min($item1,$item2))*100) . "%";
// result: $calc = "2000%"

PROBLEM RESULT:
$item1 = "8.00g";
$item2 = "14.00g";
$calc = round((max($item1,$item2) / min($item1,$item2))*100) . "%";
// result: $calc = "57%"
// I am expecting (14.00g / 8.00g)*100 = "175%"
```

Comment: Um, you know you're comparing two *strings*, right?

Comment: Btw, the second snippet gave me 5% instead of 2000%. And it's right, because `"5.00g"` is bigger than `"100.00g"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's type casting;

```
$item1 = "8.00";
$item2 = "14.00";
$calc = round((max($item1,$item2) / min($item1,$item2))*100) . "%";
```

result will be 175%

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use your strings in mathematical operations, and you know that the unit is placed at the end as it is in your example, you can cast your variables to floats:

```
$item1_numeric = (float) $item1;
```

But obviously it is better to have the values and the units separated in your variables / database.

Answer (score 0):

Use: substr($item1, 0, -1) instade of $item1, substr($item2, 0, -1) instade of $item2 when you do round.

You can't compare 2 strings with round().

Edit : If $item1 = "200g", ma solution is ok, but if if $item1 = "200.00g" you need to remove "." before round() with for example pregreplace.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, YAPHPB - and one of my favorite ones. Even though it's written in [the Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php):

```
When [max()] given a string it will be cast as an integer when comparing.
```

... it's only a partial truth: if at least one of compared values is a number, or a numeric string.

Otherwise all the strings will be compared as *strings*: first {0} characters of each strings will be compared, then {1}, then {2}... etc.

So basically that's what happens here:

```
echo max("200.00g", "50.00g"); // 50.00g, as '5' > '2'
echo max("200.00g", 50);       // "200.00g", as it gets converted to int (become 200)
```

And that's even more crazy:

```
echo max("200.00g", "1000.00"); // "200.00g", as '2' > '1'
echo max("200.00", "1000.00");  // "1000.00", as we tried to help you, no, really!
```

The latter result can actually be predicted by someone knowing of [numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) concept: when both strings are pure numbers, they got converted to numbers when compared. Still, I found this behavior unreliable, to say the least.

The bottom line: if you need to compare numbers, compare numbers, period. Type conversion in PHP can get real messy - and bite you in the bottom real hard when you least expect it. )